# How do I get rid of the drop shadow on my bindingnavigator?

Tags: c#, toolstrip, dropshadow, bindingnavigator

I've done some styling on a bindingnavigator toolstrip in my C# winforms app (VS2010), principally setting the background colour and getting rid of dividers.  It now looks like this...

[image: toolstrip]

My question is how do I get rid of the "drop shadow" effect I.e. the white single pixel lines below and to the right of the toolstrip.  I've tried tweaking the size, margins and padding of both the bindingnavigator itself and its member items but without success.

Comment: Try showing your rendering code.

Comment: Changes so far have all been through the forms designer.  They were:

1) Gripstyle hidden
2) BackColor to 120,120,120
3) Margin and padding sizes set to zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `SystemRenderer`:

```
public class MyToolStripSystemRenderer : ToolStripSystemRenderer
{
    public MyToolStripSystemRenderer() { }

    protected override void OnRenderToolStripBorder(ToolStripRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        //Making this non-op removes the artifact line that is typically drawn on the bottom edge
        //base.OnRenderToolStripBorder(e);
    }
}
```

..and then make use of it in your `ToolStrip` class in its constructor:

```
public MyToolStrip()
{
    Renderer = new MyToolStripSystemRenderer();
}
```

If this isn't an inherited `ToolStrip` control, but instead a stock control from Designer, then look in the `Designer.cs` file for the lines that set ToolStrip properties.  In mine it looks like this:

```
this.toolStrip1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
this.toolStrip1.Name = "toolStrip1";
this.toolStrip1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(678, 25);
this.toolStrip1.TabIndex = 10;
this.toolStrip1.Text = "toolStrip1";
```

Add to that, this line:

```
this.toolStrip1.Renderer = new MyToolStripSystemRenderer();
```

**Note that you could add that same line to the form's constructor if you like.  Same effect.

Comment: That makes sense.  Just one step to go then (and showing my ignorance here).  Creating the SystemRenderer is fine but how do I access the constructor for the toolstrip when it has been dropped in by the form designer rather than implemented in code?  I'm guessing the answer lies somewhere in in form.Designer.cs but I'm loathed to start tweaking that system generated stuff unless I have to.

Comment: @ifinlay Since it's in designer, you don't need the constructor.  Just add the line in the Designer.cs file.  See edit.

Comment: Dropped that into my form constructor (couple of brackets needed on the end) and bingo! All fixed.  Your help very much appreciated.

Comment: @DonBoitnott, can you help me with your code a little - I'm doing same in VB.NET but I can't figure out where to put "Renderer = new MyToolStripSystemRenderer();" in code. And I don't know If C# has same Binding Navigator, but you can't set renderer of toolstrip separately in VB.NET, just a binding navigator Itself ?

Comment: There is still a block of designer code.  And within that, code that is setting properties for the BindingNavigator.  There, you can a line such as `Me.BindingNavigator1.Renderer = New MyToolStripSystemRenderer`

Comment: I'm afraid not - no effect. Actually It has to be  " Inherits ToolStripRenderer" and not "ToolStripSystemRenderer" in VB.NET. But that removes not only a line, but separators too. Even mouse hover over items doesn't work anymore. And I've tried a lof of things to get this back - no success.